# Thrift Async Interface with Blocking server

Tags: java, thrift

Hi I am working with java and thrift. I see that there are 2 parts to the thrift Async system one is the Service.AsyncIface and another is Service.AsyncClient. From the thrift implementations for AsyncClient, I see that the non blocking interface is wired up and ready to go on the library side. I just made a simple client using TNonBlockingSocket and it works

1) Do we care if the existing thrift server for the Service is blocking or non blocking? Why?

2) If we want to wrap a nonblocking client framework in things like retry logic, host discovery, policy management etc what would be the ideal framework?

Comment: Finagle seems to be a good ticket..

Answer (score 0):

1. From client's point of view there's no difference in communication with sync or async server given that protocols and transports are compatible. That's because the client should receive the same serialized response from both sync/async servers. For example, if you do JSON over HTTP request, you don't really care if the server is sync or async.
2. Finagle is a good choice if you're interested only in JVM languages (and it's the only framework I'm aware of that has required feature set).